# Synchronizing identity server 4 instances

Tags: database, authentication, architecture, identityserver4

I work for a company that owns multiple factories, one of our goals is to allow every factory to continue operating even without a working internet connection. We host a single identity server 4 instance to manage our authentication and authorization. The authentication is done with windows authentication and the domain service is replicated across every factory. In our current setup when the connection to the central identity server is down our users cannot be authenticated.

We want to move to a setup where every factory will host its own version of identity server to authentication can happen even without a connection to the central service. The downside to this approach is that it makes configuration very tedious and error-prone. Most of our users require the same access in every factory, so if we need to update a user's claims or role we need to reconfigure this in every factory. We want to fix this by hosting a central identity server and push all changes to the local instances on a database level. We only want to allow one-way synchronization, so no local configuration or local to central pushing of data.

Are we on the right track with this approach or are we missing something? Are there any best practices for centralized configuration with localized hosting of identity server 4? Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to fix this by hosting a central identity server and push all changes to the local instances on a database level. We only want to allow one-way synchronization, so no local configuration or local to central pushing of data.

Having multi DB and data sync between them seems to be a very good option based on your requirements.
You can have a CI/CD in place for code deployment to make sure all instance apps are sync and move all configurations and user data to DB as your plan.
To sync the data you can use [SQL Data Sync for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#when-to-use) as this is the `Distributed Applications` case.

> Are we on the right track with this approach or are we missing something? Are there any best practices for centralized configuration with localized hosting of identity server 4? Any ideas will be helpful.

I'm not sure if this is much related to IdentityServer, this sounds more like a distributed application solution to me. Saying this as you might need to extend your search criteria to look for any application type with same model.